# Google Ads Api - I can create refresh token only for computer App

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I create OAuth creditionals in Google Api
[image: Create creditionals]

Problem is that if I check wep application like on the screen, and after I try to generate refresh token from this command `~/go/bin/oauth2l fetch --credentials ~/your_credentials.json --scope cloud-platform` (documentation->https://github.com/google/oauth2l) I have an error
`missing 'type' field in credentials`. Problem disappears if I check computer app instead web app. Into json file I don't have the **type**. But I need to use this API into web application. Any idea?